# How do you create interactions with other objects?

Tags: animation

I have this little Ball i made up, however i have a problem, I can get the ball to interact with other object, however i cannot get the test objects to move from the impact, what am i doing wrong?

Edit:

I placed a cylinder in the scene however the ball when making the impact with the cylinder wraps itself around the cylinder, i do not want that, i need for the cylinder to knock over or have other objects in the path to interact with the ball

[image]

Comment: Can you give a little bit more detail on what the end result that you are trying to achieve is? From the sounds of things though, you may want to consider looking into rigid body physics.

Comment: Please add screenshots of your problem and provide a .blend file to be able to help you

Comment: @Tak sorry for being late on this but I cannot find a way to post the blend file i am sorry i cannot for the life how to attach the file.

Comment: @BenMadison http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: @Tak thanks and their you go i got a old version of blender but it is safe i added so stuff to the ball to make it pretty.

Comment: @BenMadison answer provided with screenshots and an updated .blend file. You can accept the answer if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use rigid body physics to do what you want.

- Select your sphere, then add Dynamic Rigid Body to it as shown below:

[image]

- Then select your ground plane and add Passive Rigid body to it as shown below:

[image]

- This is the result, the sphere will fall and when it hits the plane it will land and stop as shown below:

[image]

Updated .blend file can be found here: [image]